# Angular 2 response url gets logged by character not in one string

Tags: angular, url, response

Hey I am new to angular2 and I am trying to get the response url like this.

```
.map(res => res.url); --this is in my service

.subscribe(data => {
 for (let entry of data){
   this.test = entry;
```

and when i log the test my url appears like this:

```
h2  home.component.ts:35 
t   home.component.ts:35
p   home.component.ts:35 
:2  home.component.ts:35
```

etc, you get the point, so why is that?
i just want to get the plain url of the response for later use.
Thanks

Comment: you want the current url of the application

Comment: no,  i make a get request and the response has a url i want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get like this, no need of for there,

```
.map(res => res.url); 
.subscribe(data => {
    this.test = data ;
}
```